# which is the best way to control a object-field type life-cycle?

Tags: delphi, oop

```
TMyClass = class(TObject)
private
  FMyObject: TObject;
  function GetMyObject: TObject;
public
  property MyObject: TObject read GetMyObject write FMyObject;
end;

function TMyClass.GetMyObject: TObject;
begin
  if FMyObject = nil then
    FMyObject := TObject.Create;

  Result := FMyObject;
end;
```

Sometimes, "MyObject" is not created internally but externally created and assigned to the parameter. If this object is created externally, I can not free it in this context.

Should I create a TList and Add in all objects that were created internally and destroy everything on the destructor?

How can I control the lifetime of a parameter if it is created internally or not? What you suggest to do? Is there any pattern to do this?

Comment: how can MyObject be created externally if it has a private access modifier? nothing expept this class sees this property

Comment: @heximal: Most likely (not in the example code) by constructor injection.

Comment: @heximal: The field is private, the property is public and read/write, ie it could be used like `Obj.MyObject := TSomeObject.Create;`.

Comment: you're right, sorry, didn't notice the property declaration

Comment: @ain In that case, the previous FMyObject instance reference created by the Getter would be gone. So @Eduardo, your property should have a setter whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

I'd set a flag in the Property Setter

```
procedure TMyClass.SetMyObject(AObject: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(MyObject) and FIsMyObject then
    FMyObject.Free;
  FIsMyObject := False;
  FMyObject := AObject;
end;

function TMyClass.GetMyObject: TObject;
begin
  if FMyObject = nil then
  begin
    FMyObject := TObject.Create;
    FIsMyObject := True;
  end;

  Result := FMyObject;
end;

Destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
    if FIsMyObject then
        FMyObject.Free;
end;
```

Comment: +1 I always do it this way. It feels a little inelegant but I've not found an alternative that I prefer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the best would be to redesign your code so that this problem won't arise - this kind of ownership ambiguity is a mess.

Anyway, one option would be to use (reference counted) interfaces. This is problematic in case of circular references.

If the externally created object must not be the only reference then you could still create internal copy of the object, something like

```
procedure TMyClass.SetMyObject(const Value: TObject);
begin
   MyObject.Assign(Value);
end;
```

You could assign external object to different field than internal and then you don't `Free` that field in destructor. Or set a flag in the property setter so that you know not to free the external object...

Comment: +1 The copy on assignment pattern is used in the VCL, so should be familiar to other Delphi developers, enhancing maintainability.

Comment: @Nat Copy on assignment is fine unless you actually want to have a reference to a shared object.

Answer (score 1):

The two most logical and practical solutions (keep a flag, copy on assignment) are already given, but for completeness sake and since the object field isn't likely to be of the TObject type, here are three other approaches. The practicality of these depends on the type of the object field, whether you really don't want an extra boolean flag and whether you dislike to add some intelligent behavior to this construction.

*(Warning: this may be a little farfetched.)*

- Test if the object field is of your private object type:

  ```
      property MyObject: TSomeAncestor read GetMyObject write SetMyObject;
    end;

  implementation

  type
    TMyObject = class(TSomeAncestor) ... end;

  destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
  begin
    if FMyObject is TMyObject then
      FMyObject.Free;
  ```
- Test on the ownership of the object field:

  ```
      property MyObject: TOwnedObject read GetMyObject write SetMyObject;
    end;

  implementation

  destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
  begin
    if FMyObject.Owner = Self then
      FMyObject.Free;
  ```

  This construction is especially useful if the external object should anyway be freed by this class: just set its Owner to this class instance. The decision depends no longer on the internal or external creation of the object.
- If the object field descends from TComponent, then you do not have to free at all.